# Getting Geometry shape of the entire OSM database

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis

I have multiply databases on postgresql/postgis.
Basically it's Database per country (might be continent for small ones).
I used osm2pgsql to import the data and it's working well.
I want to create a webserver which will get lat/lon coordinates as an input and then will access the proper DB.
In order to do so I think I need to create a geometry-object/polygon of the entire DB (again, there is a db per county), check if the lat/lon point specified is in the polygon and send the query to the right db.
How can I create such geometry/Polygon?

Thanks,
Ohad.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/13615/extract-all-country-borders If you really want to do this, have a look at the ST_Union function, which will dissolve inner boundaries, but will probably be very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitioning a database task into multiple PostgreSQL databases is usually the wrong approach. While this approach might be good one with other database software, it is not with PostreSQL. This is because it is a hassle to do cross-database queries, as you may need to do for this type of query. It is better to partition it to multiple schemas within a single database. However, if you have a million or fewer features (rows), just keep everything in the same table with an indexed country field. This way, the data will be seamless when viewing on a map or querying with SQL.

As for your [point-in-polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) question, this is the most basic GIS question, and you will find many others asking it. You will need a table of polygons representing the countries or administrative regions (e.g. http://www.gadm.org/) ideally with a GiST index, and use ST_Contains or ST_Within to determine which polygon the point is within.

Comment: Thanks! the idea of using a schema instead of db is nice, I'll defiantly consider using it. 
So here is what I did: 
I downloaded the kml files given by geofabrik for each country (e.g http://download.geofabrik.de/africa/cameroon.kml) 
(created a script for that) 
I then iterated over all the kmls, read then and created a json file which contains all the polygon coordinates of each country.